# OpenSSH 5.9p1 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: security, packaging, deb, install-from-source, openssh

I want to build a deb package with the latest version of openssh from source. Then I want to install it on my machine. 
I am running:

```
Linux Ubuntu-1110-oneiric-64-minimal 3.0.0-12-server #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:36:30 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

To achieve my goal I do:

```
wget ftp://ftp.openbsd.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz
wget ftp://ftp.openbsd.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz.asc
gpg openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz.asc 
apt-get build-dep openssh-server openssh-client
apt-get source openssh-server
cd openssh-5.8p1/
uupdate -v 5.9p1 /root/packages/openssh/openssh-5.9p1.tar.gz
cd ../openssh-5.9p1
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -nc
```

But I get an error:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/packages/openssh/openssh-5.9p1'
rm -f debian/tmp/etc/ssh/sshd_config
dh_install -Nopenssh-client-udeb -Nopenssh-server-udeb --fail-missing
cp: cannot stat `debian/tmp/usr/bin/ssh-vulnkey': No such file or directory
dh_install: cp -a debian/tmp/usr/bin/ssh-vulnkey debian/openssh-client//usr/bin/     returned exit code 1
make[1]: *** [override_dh_install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/packages/openssh/openssh-5.9p1'
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Any ideas what do I do to make this work?

Comment: hope this link help you https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssh/1:5.9p1-2ubuntu1

Answer (score 2):

I haven't investigated why it didn't build for you — perhaps there was a packaging change in `debian/`, or perhaps one of the patches (`ssh-vulnkey` is introduced in a Debian patch) needed updating — but I have just confirmed that building the 5.9p1 package from Precise on Oneiric works fine.

I used the `backportpackage` tool from `ubuntu-dev-tools` for this. Try something like this: `backportpackage -s precise -d oneiric -w . openssh`, and then build the resulting package however you like (I used `sbuild`; if you want to build using dpkg-buildpackage then you'll need to extract it with `dpkg-source -x file_name_of_dsc_file`). Make sure you get the build-depends from the package itself — `apt-get build-depends` will get you the build depends of the *Oneiric* version and not the *Precise* one that you are building. You can use `mk-build-deps` from `devscripts` for this, like so: `sudo mk-build-deps -i -r`.